# MVC - bootstrap -form control is coming in next line with form-group

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to use bootstrap formgroup. It works if I have a single label & a control but if there are more than 2 controls (label, control and validation field) then validation field goes in next line.

I tried using form-inline but no luck. Can anybody please tell me how to keep all the elements of form-group in a single line?

```
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Emp ID", new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmpID, new { disabled = "disabled", @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>

        @* Tried with form-group *@
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployementTypeID, Constants.EmploymentType, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
            <div>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EmployementTypeID, new SelectList(Model.EmploymentType, "EmployementTypeID", "EmployementTypeName", Model.EmployementTypeID), new { @class = "form-control" })
              @* This validation goes in next line, how can we keep it in the same line *@
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployementTypeID)
            </div>
        </div>

        @* Tried with form-inline *@
        <div class="form-inline">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, Constants.Address, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
            <div>
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Address, new { @class = "form-control col-sm-10" })
           @* This validation goes in next line, how can we keep it in the same line *@
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address)
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add your `class="col-sm-10"` into all of your div.

Like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployementTypeID, Constants.EmploymentType, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EmployementTypeID, new SelectList(Model.EmploymentType, "EmployementTypeID", "EmployementTypeName", Model.EmployementTypeID), new { @class = "form-control" })                  
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployementTypeID)
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: **this is correct** way of using Bootstrap Horizontal Form in asp mvc check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms.asp) for more.